# Perspective disables position:fixed in firefox 31 - 35

Tags: css, firefox, position, fixed

Today I've updated Firefox to version 31. Since then a `perspective` disables the fixed position of any child. It didn't happen in earlier versions of Firefox neither does it in Chrome.

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J8zhd/3/)**

 *FF 31-35 required*</kbd>

*Is it intended behavour or a bug? And how to avoid it?*

Comment: There is also another issue with fixed elements in FF31. When a fixed element is inside another fixed element, the inner will behave like it were absolutely positioned. Hope there will be a new version soon...

Comment: what if you go through the absolutely positioned children elements and manually set 'perspective:none;`?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this settings:

```
.perspective {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    perspective: 500px;
    top: 0;
}
```

This will make the container stay on top and be fixed.
Working Fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rxps2Lrp/)